# Technique for jquery change events and aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I need to find a reliable solution to making the two frameworks play nicely.

Using materialize-css, their select element uses jquery to apply the value change.  However that then does not trigger aurelia in seeing the change.  Using the technique of...

    `$("select")
        .change((eventObject: JQueryEventObject) => {
            fireEvent(eventObject.target, "change");
    });`

I can fire an event aurelia sees, however, aurelia then cause the event to be triggered again while it's updating it's bindings and I end up in an infinite loop.... Stack Overflow :D

Whats the most reliable way of getting the two to play together in this respect?

Comment: I wrote up a blog post covering this subject, using Semantic-UI as an example. All the concepts translate over to other frameworks. http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Answer (score 5):

I have worked with materialize-css + aurelia for a while and I can confirm that the select element from materialize is quite problematic.

I just wanted to share one of my solutions here in case anyone wants some additional examples. Ashley's is probably cleaner in this case. Mine uses a bindable for the options instead of a slot.

Other than that the basic idea is the same (using a guard variable and a micro task).

One lesson I learned in dealing with 3rd party plugins and two-way data binding is that it helps to make a more clear, distinct separation between handling changes that originate from the binding target (the select element on the DOM) and changes that originate from the binding source (e.g. the ViewModel of the page containing the element).

I tend to use change handlers with names like `onValueChangedByBindingSource` and `onValueChangedByBindingTarget` to deal with the different ways of syncing the ViewModel with the DOM in a way that results in less confusing code.

**Example: https://gist.run?id=6ee17e333cd89dc17ac62355a4b31ea9**

**src/material-select.html**

```html
<template>
    <div class="input-field">
        <select value.two-way="value" id="material-select">
            <option repeat.for="option of options" model.bind="option">
                ${option.displayName}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</template>
```

**src/material-select.ts**

```ts
import {
    customElement,
    bindable,
    bindingMode,
    TaskQueue,
    Disposable,
    BindingEngine,
    inject,
    DOM
} from "aurelia-framework";

@customElement("material-select")
@inject(DOM.Element, TaskQueue, BindingEngine)
export class MaterialSelect {
    public element: HTMLElement;
    public selectElement: HTMLSelectElement;

    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay })
    public value: { name: string, value: number };

    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneWay })
    public options: { displayName: string }[];

    constructor(
        element: Element,
        private tq: TaskQueue,
        private bindingEngine: BindingEngine
    ) {
      this.element = element;
    }

    private subscription: Disposable;
    public isAttached: boolean = false;
    public attached(): void {
        this.selectElement = <HTMLSelectElement>this.element.querySelector("select");
        this.isAttached = true;

        $(this.selectElement).material_select();
        $(this.selectElement).on("change", this.handleChangeFromNativeSelect);

        this.subscription = this.bindingEngine.collectionObserver(this.options).subscribe(() => {
            $(this.selectElement).material_select();
        });
    }

    public detached(): void {
        this.isAttached = false;
        $(this.selectElement).off("change", this.handleChangeFromNativeSelect);
        $(this.selectElement).material_select("destroy");
        this.subscription.dispose();
    }

    private valueChanged(newValue, oldValue): void {
        this.tq.queueMicroTask(() => {
            this.handleChangeFromViewModel(newValue);
        });
    }


    private _suspendUpdate = false;

    private handleChangeFromNativeSelect = () => {
        if (!this._suspendUpdate) {
            this._suspendUpdate = true;
            let event = new CustomEvent("change", {
                bubbles: true
            });
            this.selectElement.dispatchEvent(event)

            this._suspendUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    private handleChangeFromViewModel = (newValue) => {
        if (!this._suspendUpdate) {
            $(this.selectElement).material_select();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

How about a custom attribute?

**Gist: https://gist.run?id=b895966489502cc4927570c0beed3123**

**src/app.html**

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div class="input-element" style="position: relative;">
          <select md-select value.two-way="currentOption">
            <option repeat.for="option of options" model.bind="option">${option.displayName}</option>
          </select>
          <label>Selected: ${currentOption.displayName}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**src/app.ts**

```ts
export class App {
  public value: string;
  public options: {displayName: string}[];

  constructor() {
    this.options = new Array<any>();
    this.options.push({ displayName: "Option 1" });
    this.options.push({ displayName: "Option 2" });
    this.options.push({ displayName: "Option 3" });
    this.options.push({ displayName: "Option 4" });
  }

  public attached(): void {

    this.value = this.options[1];
  }
}
```

**src/md-select.ts**

```ts
import {
    customAttribute,
    bindable,
    bindingMode,
    TaskQueue,
    Disposable,
    BindingEngine,
    DOM,
    inject
} from "aurelia-framework";

@inject(DOM.Element, TaskQueue, BindingEngine)
@customAttribute("md-select")
export class MdSelect {
    public selectElement: HTMLSelectElement;

    @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay })
    public value;

    constructor(element: Element, private tq: TaskQueue) {
      this.selectElement = element;
    }

    public attached(): void {
        $(this.selectElement).material_select();
        $(this.selectElement).on("change", this.handleChangeFromNativeSelect);
    }

    public detached(): void {
        $(this.selectElement).off("change", this.handleChangeFromNativeSelect);
        $(this.selectElement).material_select("destroy");
    }

    private valueChanged(newValue, oldValue): void {
        this.tq.queueMicroTask(() => {
            this.handleChangeFromViewModel(newValue);
        });
    }


    private _suspendUpdate = false;

    private handleChangeFromNativeSelect = () => {
        if (!this._suspendUpdate) {
            this._suspendUpdate = true;
            const event = new CustomEvent("change", { bubbles: true });
            this.selectElement.dispatchEvent(event)
            this.tq.queueMicroTask(() => this._suspendUpdate = false);
        }
    }

    private handleChangeFromViewModel = (newValue) => {
        if (!this._suspendUpdate) {
            $(this.selectElement).material_select();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, this is more or less how I would probably implement this, given the goofiness of dealing with `slot` inside of a `select` element. That being said, I think both of these answers are equally valid. Your's shows off doing this with databinding, while mine shows how to accomplish something that isn't "supposed" to be possible with content projection.

Comment: You save my life, the element mode doesn't works for me, but the attribute is perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just a little bug, my data comes from a xhr request, and if a come from another route, the select shows the wrong option selected, but if I type F5 to reload page, it comes with right option selected. :/

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I spent *entirely* too long getting this one answered the way I wanted, but more on that later. The actual answer to stop the infinite loop is fairly simple, so let's look at it first. You need to have a guard property, and you'll need to use Aurelia's `TaskQueue` to help unset the guard property.

Your code will look a little something like this:

```
$(this.selectElement).change(evt => {
  if(!this.guard) {
    this.guard = true;
    const changeEvent = new Event('change');
    this.selectElement.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
    this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => this.guard = false);
  }
});
```

Notice that I'm using queueing up a microtask to unset the guard. This makes sure that everything will work the way you want.

Now that we've got that out of the way, let's look at a gist I created [here](https://gist.run/?id=6956fca943898aab90ee58ac742b4689). In this gist I created a custom element to wrap the Materialize select functionality. While creating this, I learned that `select` elements and content projection via `slot` elements don't go together. So you'll see in the code that I have to do some coding gymnastics to move the option elements over from a dummy `div` element into the `select` element. I'm going to file an issue so we can look in to this and see if this is a bug in the framework or simply a limitation of the browser.

Normally, I would highly recommend creating a custom element to wrap this functionality. Given the code I had to write to shuffle nodes around, I can't say that I *highly* recommend creating a custom element. I just *really* recommend it in this case.

But anyways, there you go!

Comment: comment regarding `slot` elements inside a `select` element. I posed the question of if this is a bug in Aurelia or just part of how the browser handles things. Patrick Walters spun up this gist: https://gist.run/?id=799d9122a3e3727c343ecf9f5c4f9b1f that shows that this is the browser, not Aurelia. So I guess we're stuck with this goofiness :-(

Comment: Wouldn't you need `as-element` in cases like this, just like you do with tables? Since `as-element` and slots dont combine very well (afaik), this might be one of this cases where `compose` could do the trick - even though I know you really don't like that ;)

Comment: The `slot` element isn't implemented internally as a "normal" Aurelia custom element. It's special, so `as-element` won't really work here. Regarding using `compose`, would you mind forking my demo to show what you mean?

Comment: It's still screwing up the binding but here's the gist so you can see what I was (kind of) trying: https://gist.run/?id=d4bd1c4962a9f3670733e498e587ba9a

I've tried multiple things but it only seems to work when the whole html (`select` + `option`s) is rendered at once and when the dropdown is initialized **after** rendering is done. Compose gives no signal for that, so I needed my own "compose" with a small adjustment.

The markup is so simple, wouldn't a custom attribute be both easier and cleaner in this case?