# Aurelia bindable and plugins/jQuery change

Tags: jquery, aurelia

I'm with a problem with bindable vars and jQuery Plugins. I've tested this code, and the bindable var is not changing:

```
<template>
  <input id="my-input" value.bind="inputvalue" type="text">
</template>
```

---

```
class MyClass {
  @bindable inputvalue;

  constructor() {
    this.inputvalue = 'First value'
  }

  bind() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('#my-input').val('Some value').change();
      // In the input element the value now is 'Some value',
      // but in bindable var this.inputvalue the value still is 'First value'
    }, 4000);
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042667/technique-for-jquery-change-events-and-aurelia